# How to change parent state from child if I am using Switch Route - React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a certain page with one control panel which is used to change current page content, which displayed using Switch-Route. It looks like this:

```
<div className="controls">
  some controls here
</div>
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/main/somepage/1/page1' component={page1} />
  <Route exact path='/main/somepage/2/page2' component={page2} />
</Switch>
```

And I have state in this page:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
  currentPage: 2,
  currentGroup: "page1",
  currentDate: new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10),
  loading: false,
})
```

What I want to do is to change the property `loading` in current state from `page1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should handle the state in the parent component or globally via the Context API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply a pattern called [Lifting State Up](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) wherein the state is promoted to a common ancestor and passed down as props to descendent components that care about it.

Example: Move the state and any callbacks into the parent component rendering the routes, and pass what you need down the specific routed components.

```
const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
  currentPage: 2,
  currentGroup: "page1",
  currentDate: new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10),
  loading: false,
});

const setLoading = (loading: boolean) => setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  loading,
}));

...

<div className="controls">
      
  ... some controls here
  
</div>
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/main/somepage/1/page1"
    render={props => <Page1 {...props} setLoading={setLoading} />}
  />
  <Route path="/main/somepage/2/page2" component={Page2} />
</Switch>
```